# Stackview different depending on device it runs on swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3, uistackview, xcode8

I have 4 buttons in a stackview.  The buttons have no kind of constraints.  The stackview is pinned to the left, right, and bottom.  No warnings for more constraints needed.  The problem is when I run it on 5 it looks fine but on any larger device it is not right.  I have the following code working with these buttons.

This makes the white lines

```
extension CGRect {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, width)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

And then I have my awake from nib to draw them.

```
class DigitButtomFrame: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        addTopBorderWithColor(color: .white, width: 1.0)
    }
}
```

[image: iPhone 5]
[image: iPhone 7s]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out whatever device I want to run simulator I have to have it selected in the view as: iPhone sections on main storyboard.